# MATLAB data file when it overs its memory

Tags: matlab, memory

There is a Matrix of 500000000 X 5.

And the sample of this data is like this :

1 01 06:0 48407
  1 01 06:1 48407
       . 
       .
       .
  865850 31 23:5 1586884493

Each column means [area_number date hour:minute amount_of_data]

I want to load them entirely, after that make another 865850 X 4464 matrix from their 5th column values. In this new matrix, row insists area_number. And each column means amout_of_data according to time priority.

This is what I wrote.

```
clear all; close all;
fileID=fopen('data2.txt','r');
Data=fscanf(fileID, '%d %d %d:%d %d',[5 100000]);
Data = Data';
Zeros = zeros(4000, 4464);
DataA = Data(:,1); % indexs
DataB = Data(:,2); % dates
DataC = Data(:,3); % hours
DataD = Data(:,4); % minutes
DataE = Data(:,5); % data
for m=1:40000
    r = DataA(m);
    c = (DataB(m)-1)*24*6 + DataC(m)*6 + DataD(m);
    Zeros(r,c) = DataE(m);
end
```

I can't finish it because the matrix too big to load it at once.
It overs memory limitation of MATLAB.

Please help me...

Thank you~!

Comment: That's to much data (47GiB). You have to process it in smaller blocks and write the result for each block to the file system.

Comment: Thank you very much~ But how can I seprate the blocks and save the results in them?

Comment: How is your data in `data2.txt` ordered?

Comment: Thank you~!!    Like this...              .                                                           1 01 06:0 48407                              ;                                                          1 01 06:1 48407         ~~                  ;                                                           865850 31 23:4 2591862482

Comment: Thank you~!!    Like this...   1 01 06:0 48407<br/>1 01 06:1 48407<br/>  .<br/>  .<br/>  .  <br/>865850 31 23:4 2591862482  <br/>865850 31 23:5 1586884493... can't change lines...

Comment: Is it sorted in time or in index? or is the data unsorted?

Comment: sorted in area number(1st column) and time(date, hour, minute).

Comment: How is this possible? Could you provide an example which contains data for three times and three areas in all combinations, so 9 lines of data?

Comment: Sorry, I said incorrectly... sorted in like this : a 1 <br/> a 2 <br/> b 1 <br/> b 2 <br/>  c 1 <br/> c 2<br/> form of data is in upper side.

Comment: I don't understand your example.

Comment: ~~~ the last three lines

Comment: 865850 31 23:3 4855891584

Comment: 865850 31 23:4 2591862482

Comment: 865850 31 23:5 1586884493

Comment: I cant help writting like this because I don't know how to chane the lines, the 1st column means area number, 2nd means date, 3rd means hour, 4th means minutes, the last means amount of data. Thank you~!

Comment: You can modify your question.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, using the `matfile` command is probably the best choice. It allows you to write data directly to a mat-file on the filesystem but access it like a variable.

If I understood your data right, all lines with the same index are next to each other, and all data with the same index is small enough to fit your memory.

1. Read all data with index 1
2. process it like you did above, creating one row of your intended matrix
3. Write this row to your matfile
4. Proceed with the next index until you reach the end